# glob() and asterisks in curly brackets

Tags: php, filenames, design-patterns, glob

I want to find some special filenames. Therefore I use [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

```
$foundResults = glob($directory . '{data_*.csv, log_*.txt}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

This code only finds my first pattern `data_*.csv`. So it seems that an asterisks is not allowed in between the curly brackets?

What are my alternatives? I can only think of using a `for each` construct to call `glob()` multiple times. Or are there better algorithms/functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct call **without the space characters**!

```
$foundResults = glob($directory . '{data_*.csv,log_*.txt}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

I got the tip from this topic: [help with glob/GLOB_BRACE](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-77040.html)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me :

```
$foundResults = glob('{tes*.php,tes*.xls}', GLOB_BRACE);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($foundResults);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => test.php
    [1] => test.xls
)
```

Check value of your `$directory` Check for trailing slash `/`. Put it if it is not there.

Comment: I have the trailing slash. I think its server specific? [Here](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-77040.html) is a similar problem. Only the first entry is found. I also tried to remove the spaces, but it is the same problem.

Comment: Ok the problem were the spaces. Before I had a caching problem so I didn't see the current results ...

Comment: Ok..so you fixed it...Cool :D

Comment: But my first problem was indeed the trailing slash. Therefore you get a +1.